# CSS Box shadow on div not working on the edge

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a div with a background color and box shadow as following:

```
position: absolute;
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
padding: 30px 20px 50px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px darkgray inset;
background-color: darkorange;
width: 250px;
height: 60%;
overflow-y: auto;
```

now, when the height is set to 60% there is a tiny orange line that is out of place:

[image: Image with orange line]

It is difficult to spot, but you can easily see it when you zoom in.
in any other height setting, the tiny line above doesn't show. Do you know what the problem is? BTW, I am using angular if that matters

EDIT:

here is the html as a snippet:

```css
.scoreboard-background{
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 30px 20px 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px darkgray inset;
  background-color: darkorange;
  width: 250px;
  height: 60%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#game-container{
  padding: 2vh 1vw;
  background-color: darkgray;
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
}

.game-background{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="game-container">
  <div class="game-background" style="">
    <div class="scoreboard-background" style="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: view it in full screen

Comment: Try inspecting the element using Dev. Tools

Comment: and then? what info do you need?

Comment: Why don't you show us the html and css? Use the snippet. It'll be far easier for us to help you resolve it.

Comment: Thats the blur property(3rd one) of box-shadow CSS. If you zoom in and increase the value. The slight blur(the line you mentioned) will be visible.

Comment: I added a snippet, and @Anand I will try it

Comment: Hey @Anand, I tried increasing the value and I don't like how it looks. Can you help me fix it where it looks the same but without the orange line at the edge? Thank you

Comment: Ya I am able to see the orange line after you added your code snippet. Let me check if I can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blur() CSS function can be used to remove that slight pixelation that occurs along the borders of the div.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur

```css
.scoreboard-datadiv {
       
        position: absolute;
        padding: 30px 20px 50px;
        width: 290px;
       
        height: 60%;
    }
    .scoreboard-background {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        padding: 30px 0px 50px;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px darkgray inset;
        background-color: darkorange;
        width: 290px;
        height: 80%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        filter: blur(3px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
        -moz-filter: blur(3px);
        -ms-filter: blur(3px);
        z-index:0;
    }
    .scoreboard-data {

       position:absolute;
       margin-left:20px;
       margin-top:10px;
       z-index:1;
    }

    #game-container {
        padding: 2vh 1vw;
        background-color: darkgray;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .game-background {
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="game-container">
    <div class="game-background" style="">
        <div class="scoreboard-datadiv">

            <div class="scoreboard-background" style="">               
            </div>
            <div class="scoreboard-data">
                Your Data
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Nice! setting the filter : blur property sure does help

Comment: Hey, this does work, but when I put other divs inside it they blur as well. Can I cancel the blur in the inner elements? Thanks

Comment: @ItaiElidan i have updated the code to cancel blur on inner elements.